# WPF, Prism, MEF. Register region adapter within a module?

Tags: wpf, prism, mef, prism-4, regionadapter

Is it possible to register a region adapter within a module?

I have a ContentControl in my Shell.xaml set to region "MainRegion" that currently gets populated with a module containing the AvalonDock control. I currently have the AvalonDock region adapter in my Shell app but would like to place it in the module and register itself. I want to keep this program flexible so that if we decide to use something other than AvalonDock, I can easily use another module without having to modify my Shell assembly (removing the avalondock region adapter).

I imagine something like this is possible. Has anyone done this before?

In bootstrapper right now is:

```
protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
{
    RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
    var regionBehaviorFactory = Container.GetExportedValue<IRegionBehaviorFactory>();
    var regionManager = Container.GetExportedValue<IRegionManager>();
    mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(Pane), new AvalonRegionAdapter(regionBehaviorFactory, regionManager));

    return mappings;
}
```

This is what I would like to perform in the Module instead of the Shell bootstrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is here from codeplex  http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/250892

> The scenario you're describing is
>   possible. Although custom region
>   adapters are intended to be registered
>   in the RegionAdapterMappings in the
>   Bootstrapper's
>   ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings method,
>   it is possible to register a custom
>   region adapter from within a module.
>
> You could, for example, obtain a
>   reference to the RegionAdapterMappings
>   in your Module class by using
>   constructor injection, and call the
>   RegisterMapping method there. This is
>   possible since there is a class named
>   MefRegionAdapterMappings, which
>   exports the RegionAdapterMappings as a
>   shared export. Note that you should be
>   aware of the timing issues that may
>   arise due to this. You should be
>   careful to register the custom mapping
>   before attempting to create a region
>   which uses that adapter.